# Trying to fire UILocalNotification not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilocalnotification

I'm using the code below to create a notification, but somehow it's not firing. I really just want it to trigger as I open one certain view controller, but nothing is firing so far. What is the problem with my code?

```
func notify() {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = Date()
    notification.repeatInterval = .minute
    notification.alertBody = "The alert body"
    notification.alertAction = "enter text here"
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

I also have this line in the app delegate:

```
application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason I believe this would fail is because `notification.fireDate = Date()`  will set the `fireDate` to the current time, which will be in the past by the time the (separate) process managing UserNotifications is alerted that you want to fire a notification. Consider moving to `UNNotification`s

Comment: This was it! When I changed the date to a little bit later, it worked again and gave me notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the firing date to a certain time in the future (it was 6 PM where I changed it to 06:03 by using calendarComponents, and then it seemed to work. The notification got fired :)